# Rails - How to give users edit rights over specific posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

For my application, I have users who make project postings.  Each post is only editable by only the original poster.  I want to build a function that allows the original user to give other users of original poster's choosing access/edit rights.  How would I go about doing this?

**project.rb**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :user
  ...
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :projects
  ...
end
```

**projects_controller.rb**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:edit]

  def edit
    if current_user == Project.find(params[:id]).user || current_user.try(:admin?)
        @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    else
        redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: You need to first think how you will store it, before getting into the authorization part.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the user has category which is something like?

"Admin", "General User" , "Owner"

code sample will be

```
def check_owner
ret = false
if post.user_id = current_user.id
  ret true
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like authorization here to me. If its to do with some sort of authoritive access to edit something then my best bet is that you do this with CanCan. So you could have an Admin user that can grant users particular access right, based on their role. https://github.com/ryanb/cancan Not sure if this is exactly what your looking for. Because I mean as an example you could effectively have something like this defined in your `user_controller`

```
 def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if current_user.role? :administrator
      #Allow admin to access everyone account
    else
      access_denied unless current_user?(@user)
    end
  end
```

Also with CanCan you can define your access right in your `abilities.rb` by doing something like:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user
   # raise user.role?(:administrator).inspect
    if user.role? :administrator

      can :manage, :all
      can :manage, User

    elsif user.role? :employee
      can :read, :all

    end

  end
end
```

Not 100% sure if this is what your after. Hope this helps anyways